# Declaring function usable throughout project

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and I am trying to figure out how to add a function that could be usable throughout the entire project. A simple function like

```
func globalFunction() {
    println("Global function!")
}
```

Then be able to call this function on any swift file within my project. Where would I declare this function?

Comment: Just declare it outside of any class.

Answer (score 1):

Its just like in any programming language - declaring the function outside the class, something like:

```
class A
{
   var a:Int
   // you can call your global function here
}
class B
{
  var b:Int
  // and here
}

func flobalFunction()
{
   println("Hello, I am a global function!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use static functions if you still want to bind the method to a class:

```
class myClass{
  static func globalFunc() -> Void {
    println("This is it")
  }
}


myClass.globalFunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `.swift` file in your project and declare your functions. Functions declared in this file will be available in the same module.

> By default, variables, constants, and other named declarations that
>   are declared at the top-level of a source file are accessible to code
>   in every source file that is part of the same module.

Taken from [The Swift programming language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID352), see section on **Top-Level Code**.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a helper function, you can create a new Swift file, and place the function in it else place it in any class as:

```
Class HelperFunctionsClass() {
   func anyFunction () {
   //Your implementation of the function here
   }
}
```

To use this, create an instance of the class in the place you would like to use it as:

```
var instanceOfHelperFunctionClass = HelperFunctionClass()
```

Now simply use this instance variable to use the function as:

```
insttanceOfHelperFunctionClass.anyFunction()
```